# The properties of the odd function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $f(x) = \frac{x^2 + f(x+2)}{2}$ , f is an odd function , find $f(-1)$
Turn no.1
Put x = -1 , then $$f(-1)= -f(1) =- \frac{1 + f(3)}{2}$$ put x = 3
$$f(3) = -f(-3) = -\frac{9 + f(-1)}{2}$$
By substitution from one equation into the other we get that
$$\frac{3}{4} f(-1) = \frac{7}{4}$$ then 
$$f(-1) = \frac{7}{3}$$
Turn no.2
Put x = -1
Then
$$f(-1) = \frac{1 + f(1)}{2}$$ but
$$f(1) = -f(-1) $$ then
$$f(-1) = \frac{1-f(-1)}{2}$$ 
$$f(-1) = \frac{1}{3}$$ 
Which solution is correct ? I think the second solution is not correct because it considered that 
$f(x+2) $ is an odd which is not correct ?

Comment: I don't see any errors in either method. This means there is no odd function satisfying the given equation.

Comment: @ Hussien Mohamed  The difference equation is linear and inhomogeneous, hence standard techniques can be applied which lead to the following general solution for integer $n$:  $f(n) = 12+4 n + n^2 + 2^{\frac{n}{2}} \left( A+ (-1)^n B \right)$ with $A$ and $B$ constants. This function is neither symmetric nor antisymmetric. Hence there is no solution to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=-f(-x)=-{x^2+f(-x+2)\over 2}= -{x^2-f(x-2)\over 2}$$

Since:

$$ f(x-2) = {(x-2)^2+f(x)\over 2}$$

So $$2f(x) = -x^2+{(x-2)^2+f(x)\over 2}$$ so

$$3f(x)=-2x^2+(x-2)^2$$

so $$f(x) = {-x^2-4x+4\over 2}$$

but this function is not odd. So no such functions.